# How to return a singleton object for an entity

Tags: java, singleton

How to return a singleton object for an entity, what would be more appropriate to use?

```
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList-T-
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`API Support:` SingletonList support sorting API which is not in the case of List.Of

`Null Support:` If you're planning (for some strange reason) to intentionally create a single-element list with a null element, you cannot use List:of. It will NullPointerException your face (yes, friends, "NullPointerException" can be used as verb). The same is true for Array::asList and the Stream-based approaches.
Collections::singletonList will happily create a List of null.

`Performance:` Throughput is slightly higher and average execution time is trivially faster for Collections::singletonList than List::of, but they offer basically identical performance.

**Conclusion:**

Both Collections::singletonList and List:of are great choices for creating single-element lists. If you're fortunate enough to be using a version of Java that supports both methods (9 and above), then I recommend going with List:of for its ease of use, readability, and better-documented immutability.

Answer (score 1):

Either. No way to make a more specific recommendation without a specific situation.

Or take [Dr. Joshua Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch)’s advice in [*Effective Java*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34927404-effective-java) and use an enum. See [tutorial on enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) by Oracle.

```java
public enum ExampleSingleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

Usage:

```java
System.out.println(
    ExampleSingleton.INSTANCE
);
```

You can add a constructor and methods to that enum class, if needed. An enum can also implement interfaces. And, new in Java 16, an [enum can be defined locally](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).